# What happens to thread as onDestroy is called when device is rotated

Tags: android, multithreading, persistence, android-activity, destroy

I would like to know as to what will happen to the thread which has been created by an activity and the device is rotated. I have observed that the onDestroy method is called when this happens. Will the thread be killed too?

If the thread is not killed, how can I reassociate the thread with the activity as a new instance of the activity is created on rotation.

Thanks,

Lakshmie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thread is not killed.  You can keep a reference to your thread by overriding [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()) to save the thread object and then [`getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance()) to get it back.